# The Android LoaderManager is deprecated. Now what?

Tags: java, android, deprecated, android-loadermanager

The Android LoaderManager is deprecated and i want to know what is available now to do the same functionality. If there is anything, Please also post the links where i can learn the new thing.Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the appropriate replacement of deprecated getSupportLoaderManager()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51408098/what-is-the-appropriate-replacement-of-deprecated-getsupportloadermanager)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/LoaderManager

When you see something is deprecated, go directly to the developer's site, find needed class or method which already mark it as deprecated and there will be a better alternative.

> This class was deprecated in API level 28. Use the Support Library
>   [LoaderManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/LoaderManager.html?hl=en)